# How to use flowArguments to pass values from a Digital Experience page into a flow?

Tags: community, visual-workflow, digital-experience

I had a flow that has this input variable:

```
<variables>
    <name>PolicyName</name>
    <dataType>String</dataType>
    <isCollection>false</isCollection>
    <isInput>true</isInput>
    <isOutput>false</isOutput>
</variables>
```

and wanted to pass a constant value in from a Digital Experience page. That page's metadata included:

```
}, {
  "components" : [ {
    "componentAttributes" : {
      "flowArguments" : "",
      "flowLayout" : "oneColumn",
      "flowName" : "acl__NewRegistration2"
    },
    "componentName" : "forceCommunity:flowCommunity",
    "id" : "09ac8e2a-cd8f-4a28-95e7-a580dda9c6b9",
    "renderPriority" : "NEUTRAL",
    "renditionMap" : { },
    "type" : "component"
  } ],
  "id" : "2947bfe5-f3ee-4faf-63ec-ff0189ba4c8a",
  "regionName" : "content",
  "type" : "region"
}, {
```

but I couldn't find any documentation on the `flowArguments` string that looked like the way to do that. What should that contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a value in the Experience Builder:

[image: screen shot of builder]

then doing an SFDX revealed this array of JSON objects syntax for `flowArguments`:

```
"flowArguments" : "[{\"label\":\"PolicyName\",\"dataType\":\"String\",\"supportsRecordId\":false,\"value\":\"ExamplePolicy\"}]",
```

i.e. this JSON turned into a string:

```
[
    {
        "label":"PolicyName",
        "dataType":"String",
        "supportsRecordId":false,
        "value":"ExamplePolicy"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass the input value from Digital Experience into flow using URL parameter page.

Edit Flow setup variable for **PolicyName** as **{!paramURLPolicyName}** (any name with **{!...}** )

and access the page, add the parameter on URL like this example
https://yourdomain.cs73.force.com/s/yourpageurl?paramURLPolicyName=policy001

[image]

Comment: Not OP, but this is DEFINITELY what I was looking for when I ended up here.  Now I can pass in URL arguments with a Digital Experience page, directly into a flow.  Perfect for CSAT surveys (in my case).